# How to get SDL_CreateWindow definition

Tags: c++, sdl

I was trying to learn SDL2 and was trying to figure out how SDL_CreateWindow was implemented. All I could find out was this

```
extern DECLSPEC SDL_Window * SDLCALL SDL_CreateWindow(const char *title,
                                                      int x, int y, int w,
                                                      int h, Uint32 flags);
```

and a #define in the code

```
#define SDL_CreateWindow SDL_CreateWindow_REAL
```

Is it loaded via a dll or something? Is there a way I can see the definition?

I tried looking around the SDL.sln but didnt get any good matches.

Comment: SDL is open source, [all of the source is available](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL) for download. You can simply download it and check for yourself.

Comment: It's in a library or DLL somewhere (I don't know enough about SDL to know for sure) and there's no way you can get the source code from that. Maybe SDL is an open source library (again I don't actually know) but if it is then you can find the source online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those `*_REAL`-suffixed names are an artifact of SDL's [dynapi system](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/main/docs/README-dynapi.md) that lets end-users update the SDL version of programs that statically link against it.

[`git grep`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep)-ing [the source](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/tree/release-2.26.1) for `SDL_CreateWindowTexture` should lead you to the actual implementation at [`src/video/SDL_video.c:221`](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/release-2.26.1/src/video/SDL_video.c#L221-L335)

Comment: While informative, it's all a copy-paste from the linked page. This would be better as just a simple comment.